# return a date object or string from a momentjs object created with a time string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I have this time in the sql server saved: '12:45:00'

I need to show this time in a html timepicker which wants the time in the following:

Timepicker directive: "ng-model" value must be

- a Date object,
- a number of milliseconds since 01.01.1970 or
- a string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date

How do I have to use the momentjs library that I can bind my value to the timepicker?

Comment: You don't need moment.js, just use Date object: `new Date(datetime)`. Time on the server should be datetime format.

Comment: I do not want to save the time on the server as datetime as its unnecessary. I just have the TIME. And doing moment("08:30:59") doesn`t give me anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
moment(endTime,"HH:mm").toDate();
```

---

This way I get just the time and the date is implicitly created - which I do not need -

Answer (score 0):

If your web service returns dates as strings in its responses, in most cases it's a good idea to use an [`$http` transformer](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http/#transforming-requests-and-responses) to convert them into Date objects that you can more easily work with in your JavaScript. Working with native JavaScript Date objects means that you can consistently bind directly to your models, use `$filter`s more easily, and manipulate dates and times without having to worry about conversions here or there.

This transformer looks for dates in ISO8601 format in any data returned in a response to a `$http` request, validates them with Moment.js and converts them into JavaScript Date objects.

```
$httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse.push(function (data) {
    /**
    * Converts ISO 8601 date strings returned by the web service into
    * JavaScript Date objects.
    * @param {Object} obj The server response
    * @return {Object}
    */
    var convertDateStringsToDates = function (obj) {
        // Matches format: 2014-07-23T00:00:00
        var regex = /\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\dT[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d/;
        var name, value, match, dt;

        for (name in obj) {
            if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(name)) { continue; }

            value = obj[name];

            // Check for string properties which look like dates
            if (typeof value === 'string' && (match = value.match(regex))) {
                dt = moment(match[0]);

                // confirm parseable by Moment.js
                if (dt.isValid()) {
                    obj[name] = dt.toDate();
                }
            } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
                // Recurse into the object
                convertDateStringsToDates(value);
            }
        }

        return obj;
    };

    // Ignore things that are not objects
    return typeof data === 'object' ? convertDateStringsToDates(data) : data;
});
```